# Find the probability density function of sum of two marginal probability density functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint probability density function
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
2,  & \text{if x $\ge$ 0, y $\ge$ 0 , $x + y$ $\le$ 1} \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

let $W = X + Y$

My question is how I calculate the probabilty density function $f_W(w)$ from here?

If calculated the marginal probabilty density functions
$$f_x(x) = 2-2x  \text{ for }   0 \le x \le 1$$
$$f_Y(y) = 2-2y  \text{ for }   0 \le y \le 1$$

But i have no clue how to go from here to the probability density function $f_W(w)$

Any pointers or solutions are highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The marginals you calculated look "suspicious". They can take positive values outside $[0,1]$ while $(X,Y)$ has a subset of $[0,1]^2$ as support. There is definitely something wrong with your calculation. Fortunately you do not need them for calculating $f_W(w)$.

Comment: Made a typo in the marginals, they should be correct now.

Comment: Not completely. Also $0\leq x\leq 2$ must be changed into $0\leq x\leq 1$. Same story of $y$.

Comment: You're right, they should be complete now .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $w\geq0$ define triangle: $$\Delta_w=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\mid x+y\leq w\}$$

Then $(X,Y)$ has uniform distribution on triangle $\Delta_1$

For $w\in[0,1]$ we find: $$F_W(w)=P(X+Y\leq w)=P((X,Y)\in\Delta_w)=2\lambda(\Delta_w)=w^2$$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

The PDF of $W$ can be found as derivative of the CDF, i.e. for $w\in[0,1]$ we have:$$f_W(w)=2w$$
Further we can take $f_W(w)=0$ if $w\notin[0,1]$.